# How to show #Hom$(C_a, G)=\{x\in G: x^a=e\}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I am willing to establish that $$\#\text{Hom}(C_a, G)=\#\{x\in G: x^a=e\}$$ where $G$ is finite group of order $n$ and $C_a$ is cyclic group of order $a$.

I started like this: By first isomorphism theorem, we shall have 
$$\frac{C_a}{\ker f}≃ Im(f)\leq G$$ if $f:C_a\rightarrow G$ be some group homomorphism. Hence $|ker(f)|$ is divisor of $a$.

After this part, I am unable to finish the track. Can some one help me please ?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $C_a$ is cyclic, to define a group homomorphism $C_a\to G$, it is enough to define the image of a generator of $C_a$.

More precisely : if $C_a=\langle g\rangle$ with $ord(g)=a$, then to obtain $f:C_a\to G$ it suffices to choose a good $x\in G$ and define $f(g^n)=x^n$ for all $g^n\in C_a$. Then for any $g^m,g^{n}\in C_a$, $$f(g^mg^n)=f(g^{m+n})=x^{m+n}=x^mx^n=f(g^m)f(g^n),$$which shows that $f$ is indeed an homomorphism.

Of course you can't do this for any $x\in G$ : indeed $g^a=e$ in $C_a$, so you need to have $x^a=e$ in $G$, otherwise $f$ wouldn't be correctly defined. But if it is the case, then $f$ is well-defined, because $g^n=g^{n'}$ iff $g^{n-n'}=e$ iff $n-n'$ is a multiple of $a$, and then $x^{n-n'}=e$, so $x^n=x^{n'}$ as well.

All this shows that there is a bijection $Hom(C_a,G)\leftrightarrow \{x\in G|x^a=e\}$; as a consequence, their cardinals are equal.

Comment: Dear sir, please explain why $x^m x^n=f(g)^m$. or is there any edit is required ?

Comment: There was indeed an edit required :)

Answer (score 2):

I would take a different approach: Let $C$ be the infinite cyclic group, and let 
$$\pi:C\to C_a,\quad n\mapsto b^n$$ be a canonical epimorphism, where $b$ is any generator of $C_a$. Then a homomorphism $\varphi:C_a\to G$ induces a homomorphism $\varphi\pi:C\to G$ such that $\varphi\pi[aC]=\{e_G\}$. On the other hand, any homomorphism $\psi:C\to G$ such that $\psi[aC]=\{e_G\}$ induces a unique homomorphism $\bar\psi:C_a\to G$ such that $\bar\psi\pi = \psi$. So homomorphisms $C_a\to G$ correspond to homomorphisms $\psi:C\to G$ such that $\psi(a)=e_G$.

Do you know how homomorphisms $\psi:C\to G$ can be characterized? And can you figure out which of these satisfy $\psi(a)=e_G$ ?